# Dashed arrow on a chessboard

Tags: tikz-pgf, chessboard

The Latex below draws a board with an arrow. How can I change the appearance of the arrow line, so that it is **dashed**?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\newgame
\chessboard[
    setfen=r1bqkbnr/pp1ppppp/2n6/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2,
    pgfstyle=straightmove,
    markmoves={f1-b5}
]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: board]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, \newgame is not define. Beside this with some care you can use tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard,tikz}

\begin{document}

\chessboard[
    setfen=r1bqkbnr/pp1ppppp/2n6/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2,
    addpgf={\tikz[overlay]\draw[red,line width=0.1em,->,dashed](f1)--(b5);},
]

\end{document}
```

[image]